# check_box_outline icon takes additional space

Tags: angular, angular-material2, google-material-icons

I have some trouble with my component's design using angular and angular-material frameworks.

Everything is based on a `mat-sidenav-container`. The sidenav contains accordion - the expandable list of, let's say "categories". Within each expansion panel there is a selection list of items. So far, so good.

Above the the selection list I added a regular `mat-list` which contains one item. The item contains the caption and the "select all" option. For "select all" utility I used the relevant, clickable `mat-icon`.

Everything seemed to work well, except the situation when `mat-icon` is set to `check_box_outline`. Such icon causes the horizontal scroll bar appears within side nav. It looks like there is some blank space added after the icon, but I don't understand why. It doesn't appear for other icons, neither `check_box_outline_blank` nor `indeterminate_check_box`.

[image: the icon causes the horizontal scroll bar appeard]

Has anyone the idea what exactely caused this bug and how to prevent the scroll bar appearance?

I put the relevant code and a demo [on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxr4ec) (within the `app` folder). I kept the code as simple as possible just to demonstrate the issue. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the F12 tools, I cannot see the width of the faulty element but it looks as if the inner content of the `mat-icon` element is taken into account in the overflow of the `mat-sidenav` container:

```
<mat-icon _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">
              check_box_outline
</mat-icon>
```

When I edit `check_box_outline` in the rendered HTML, the scrollbar adapts to the new content, even if that content is not displayed.

Adding the following CSS style to styles.css appears to solve the problem (see [the modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxr4ec-trlzjh)):

```
.material-icons {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```